# Как заново отправить запрос после обновления токена?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-middleware

Ситуация такая: я отправляю запрос на получение каких то данных и получаю ответ о том что срок токена истек. Далее я должен обновить токен и заново отправить запрос который посылал в начале. Как это сделать используя redux-toolkit и middleware?

Middleware для перехвата ошибок:

```
import { doRefreshToken } from "../reducers/user";

const TOKEN_EXPIRED_ERROR = "tokenExpiredException";

const tokenMiddleware = (api) => (next) => (action) => {
    const result = next(action);

    if (action.type === TOKEN_EXPIRED_ERROR) {
        const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
        api.dispatch(doRefreshToken({ refreshToken })).then(() => {
            // dispatch new action
        });
    }

    return result;
};

export default tokenMiddleware;
```

Запрос который нужно послать после обновления токена:

```
const getSmth = createAsyncThunk("user/getSmth ", async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
        const response = await api.get("/smth");
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response);
    }
});
```

Важно: уметь отправлять не только запрос getSmth но и любой другой, а так же делать это нужно именно в middleware